# Remembering the state of the tree view menu on refreshing the page in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, treeview, jtree

I have a tree view menu in ruby. 
I am expanding the tree and it works well.
On refreshing the page it collapsesand my expansion is not seen.
Please let me know if there is a way to rember the state of the tree view.

my view code:

```
%table.treeTable
%thead
%th
  All:
  = link_to "Expand", "#", :class => "all_action_expand"
  = "/"
  = link_to "Collapse", "#", :class => "all_action_collapse"
%th
  = link_to "Check", "#", :class => "check_all"
  = "/"
  = link_to "Uncheck", "#", :class => "uncheck_all"


%tbody 
- Ic.make_tree(@ics).values.each do |root|
  %tr{:id => root.tree_id, :class => "root"}
    %td= root.root_name
    - if show_check_boxes
      %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", root.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
  - root.suites.each do |suite|
    %tr{:id => suite.tree_id, :class => "child-of-#{root.tree_id}"}
      %td= suite.suite_name
      - if show_check_boxes
        %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", suite.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
    - suite.children.each do |case_item|
      %tr{:id => case_item.tree_id, :class => "child-of-#{suite.tree_id}"}
        %td= case_item.case_name
        - if show_check_boxes
          %td= check_box_tag "ic_glob", case_item.tree_id, false, :class => "ic_parent"
      - case_item.children.each do |ic|
        %tr{:id => ic.id, :class => "child-of-#{case_item.tree_id}"}
          %td= link_to ic.name, edit_ic_path(ic.id)
          - if show_check_boxes
            %td= check_box_tag "ic_ids[]", ic.id, false
  /Execute the tree table javascript (hackish)
  = javascript_tag "$('.treeTable').treeTable({persist:true})"
  / Need some Ic javascript to (cascading selects, etc.)
  = javascript_include_tag "pages/ic"
  = javascript_include_tag "jquery.cookie"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cookie to store the actual state of your tree. When you reload the page, read the cookie and restore the expansion.

**EDIT:**

You need the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin, then use the [`persist`](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/#settings) parameter to restore the tree expansions after reload automagically:

```
$(".example").treeTable({
  persist: true
});
```

Comment: Could you please give me a link or example for this.

Comment: @ramaya This depends very much on your implementation. As you did not give any additional information about techniques you used it is hard to give advice. Some ideas: every time you change the state (expand/collaps) save this to a cookie, what parts of your tree are expanded. When you reload your page take this cookie and use it to re-expand all parts of your tree that were expanded before.

Comment: yes this is what exactly i need.Can u help with the plugin required for this.

Comment: @ramya I do not know any plugin for this, sorry. But if you add some code or examples to your question I might help.

Comment: Hi I have downloaded the jquery.cookie.js and I am trying to use this in my jquery.treeTable.js file.I have modified the question with the code.Please help me out if modifications are required.

Comment: Hi Arnep, thanks a lot for your answer.I have downloaded the jquery cookie. I am not able to find a way to store and retrieve the state via cookie.

Comment: You just need to set the `persist: true` parameter during treetable initialization. There is no need to do anything with jquery-cookie than include it via `<script src="jquery.cookie.js" ...></script>`

Comment: Hi Arnep,I have changed my view code to the one in the question.But I am not able to see the state being persistent.Please help me out.

Comment: @ramya Have you downloaded the latest version of jquery, jquery.cookie and jquery.treeview? Clear all cache and cookies in your browser and set up a minimal example with just this functionality. This worked for me.